# python regular expression to grab username froma webpage code

Tags: python

i only want to scrap username from a webpage , the username change everytime i loged in

here is the code

```
</tr><tr><td>Phone Number:</td><td>(701) 684-1390</td></tr><tr><td>Username:</td><td>**Username here**</td></tr>
```

So how can i only grab the username by using regex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `BeautifulSoup` parser.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
HTML_Text = '''</tr><tr><td>Phone Number:</td><td>(701) 684-1390</td></tr><tr><td>Username:</td><td>Username here</td></tr>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML_Text, 'html.parser')

td = soup.select('td')
for i,j in enumerate(td):
    if j.text == 'Username:':
        print td[i+1].text
        break
```

Output:

```
Username here
```

Comment: okay i find out how to grab username with regex ,but when ever i try to write user name in a file , am getting bracked andcomma                                                                                                           ['brandanodomBju'] , how to remove those ?